# How to apply required check on mat-expansion-panel

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a form which shows a upload panel (mat-expansion-panel) to upload documents. I need to show asterisk (`*`) mark over the mat-expansion-panel to show it as required mark. I am aware we can asterisk(`*`) mark by setting required property for `<textarea>` or `<input>` fields. But I didn't found a way to apply it over mat-expansion-panel

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/nqegnprnrap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts                                                                  check out mat-expansion-panel-header > mat-panel-title

Comment: you can add * also inside text of <mat-panel-title> to show it as required expansion panel.

Comment: how can we avoid hard coding and drive it by property.Also it won't take red font as used by required variable.

Comment: I would look into creating an directive to append the asterisk to the title when your form group contains a required field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the example at Angular Material:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/nqegnprnrap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts

You can simply just add the asterisk next to the title of the panel.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Personal data *
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Type your name and age
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: how can we avoid hard coding and drive it by property.Also it won't take red font as used by required variable.

Comment: I think you need to work on creating your own FormControl or FormGroup, and then depending on the validity of that controller or group, you add custom error messages, and handle the red text yourself. The mat-accordion is not a Form element. You need to do create it your self. I would recommend using Angular Reactive Forms or Template driven forms instead of relying on vanilla html form validation. Especially when you need something as you do.